# SELENIUM WEBDRIVER : What is serenity framework

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have heard about serenity framework is 20 times faster performance than web- driver. Is that true. If so please be explain.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Serenity and webdriver are not connected in any way.

Webdriver is a collection of language specific bindings to drive a browser. More information http://docs.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/

Serenity (previously thucydides) is framework for behaviour-driven development. More information http://www.thucydides.info/